# Fastlane set options auto value

Tags: fastlane

I would like to submit my lane with optional options. So for example the lane:

```
lane :mylane do |options|
  mailgun(
      to: "#{options[:mailto]}"
      ....
    )
end
```

How do I give `:mailto` a default value? So if I would run `fastlane mylane` it would automatically set `:mailto` to mail@example.com.

But if I would run`fastlane mylane mailto:"secondmail@example.com"` it would use that value

Answer (score 17):

As Lyndsey Ferguson pointed out in a comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47370193/1032372), the following is simplest:

```
mail_addr = options.fetch(:mailto, 'mail@example.com')
```

where the first parameter of `fetch` is the option to fetch, and the second is the default value if the option was not passed in.

I just want to add that this works a lot better than the other suggestion:

```
options[:mailto] || 'mail@example.com'
```

when dealing with boolean options.

Fastlane (or maybe Ruby) interprets `true`, `false`, `yes`, and `no` as boolean values instead of strings (maybe others too, though I tried `N`, `n`, `NO`, and `FALSE` and they were treated as strings), so if in your lane implementation you had:

```
options[:my_option] || true
```

or

```
(options[:my_option] || 'true') == 'true'
```

you would get unexpected behaviour.

If you didn't pass in `myOption` at all, this would default to `true` as you would expect. If you passed in `true` this would also return `true`. But if you passed in `false` this would turn into `true`, which you of course wouldn't want.

Using `options.fetch(:myOption, true)` works great with boolean flags like the ones mentioned above and therefore seems better to use in general.

Here's a very thorough example in case you want to test it yourself:

```
lane :my_lane do |options|
    puts("You passed in #{options[:my_option]}")

    my_option = options[:my_option] || true
    if my_option
        puts('Using options[:my_option], the result is true')
    else
        puts('Using options[:my_option] the result is false')
    end

    my_option_fetched = options.fetch(:my_option, true)
    if my_option_fetched
        puts('Using fetched, the result is true')
    else
        puts('Using fetched, the result is false')
    end
end
```

Outputs:

`fastlane my_lane my_option:true`

> You passed in true
> Using options[:my_option], the result is true
> Using fetched, the result is true

`fastlane my_lane my_option:false`

> You passed in false
> Using options[:my_option], the result is true
> Using fetched, the result is false

`fastlane my_lane my_option:no`

> You passed in false
> Using options[:my_option], the result is true
> Using fetched, the result is false

Note, e.g. `FALSE` would default to `true` as it is not being interpreted as a boolean, which seems reasonable to me.

(Fastlane 1.77.0, Ruby 2.7.2)

EDIT: It's worth noting that if you pass an empty string instead of nothing/null you would not get the default value from the `fetch` method.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure there's a way to make Fastlane pass a default. The processing is pretty simple:

https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/blob/master/fastlane/lib/fastlane/command_line_handler.rb#L10

But you can easily do this in your Fastfile:

```
lane :mylane do |options|
  mail_addr = options[:mailto] || "mail@example.com"
  mailgun(
      to: "#{mail_addr}"
      ....
    )
end
```

Comment: I suggest that you use `mail_addr = options.fetch(:mailto, 'mail@example.com')` and you'll get the default if the `:mailto` key does not exist in the `options`. Its a little simpler.

Comment: And where would I specify the default then?